# Formulating the master theorem with Little-O- and Little-Omega notation

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, asymptotics, master-theorem

In a lecture of Algorithms of Data Structures (based on Cormen et al.), we defined the master theorem like this:

> Let $a \geq 1$ and $b \gt 1$ be constants, and let $T : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $T(n) = aT(\frac{n}{b}) + f(n)$, then
>   $ \\ T\in\left\{\begin{matrix}
> \Theta(n^{\log_b{a}}), & \text{ if } f \in O(n^{log_b{a}-\epsilon}) \text{ for some } \epsilon > 0. \\
> \Theta(n^{\log_b{a}} \log{n}), & \text{ if } f \in \Theta(n^{\log_b{a}}). \\
> \Theta(f), & \text{ if } f \in \Omega(n^{\log_b{a}+\epsilon}) \text{ for some } \epsilon > 0 \\
> & \text{ and if the regularity condition holds. }
> \end{matrix}\right.$

When I first had to study this theorem, I found that for me personally, the meaning of $\epsilon$ was somewhat difficult to understand and memorise. I believe to have found a simpler way to write this theorem, and I am wondering if it can be used equivalently, or if there is a flaw in my reasoning.

Let's look at the first case in particular, $f \in O(n^{log_b{a}-\epsilon})$. For simplicitly, let's assume $\log_b(a) = 2$. If we choose an infinitesimally small value for $\epsilon$, then this case basically expresses that $f$ must be asymptotically less than or equal to $n^{1.999 \ldots}$. In other words, $f$ must be asymptotically strictly less than $n^2$. I am wondering if this means that we can write this first case of the theorem as $f \in o(n^{\log_b{a}})$ (and following the same logic, $f \in \omega(n^{\log_b{a}})$ for the third case), rather than the (IMO) more convoluted alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am wondering if this means that we can write this first case of the theorem as $f \in o(n^{\log_b{a}})$ (and following the same logic, $f \in \omega(n^{\log_b{a}})$ for the third case), rather than the more convoluted alternative?

That is indeed a natural attempt to understand that "convoluted" condition in simple terms. Unfortunately, it is not correct.

Here is a simple counterexample. Let $a=1$ and $b=2$, and let $T : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $T(n) = T(\frac{n}{2}) + f(n)$ and $T(1)=0$, where $f(n)=\frac1{\ln n} \in o(1)=o(n^{\log_21})$.

If the first case of master theorem still holds, we should have $T(n) \in \Theta(n^{\log_21})=\Theta(1)$. However,
$$T(2^m)=T(2^{m-1})+\frac1m=T(2^{m-2})+\frac1m+\frac1{m-1}=\cdots=\frac1m+\frac1{m-1}+\cdots+1.$$
Letting $m$ goes to infinity, we see that $T(n)$ is not bounded because the harmonic series diverges.

---

For the same or a variety of other reasons, the usage of an arbitrarily small positive constant, which is usually denoted by $\epsilon$ pops up constantly in different places, especially in asymptotic estimate and complexity analysis.  You may want to get used to it or even get addicted to it.

---

**Exercise 1.** Verify that for any $\epsilon>0$, it is not true that $\frac1{\ln n}\in o(n^{-\epsilon})$ although  $\frac1{\ln n}\in o(n^0).$

**Exercise 2.** Construct a counterexample for the master theorem where $a=4$, $b=2$ for

- the first case where $f \in o(n^{\log_b{a}})$ instead of $ f \in O(n^{log_b{a}-\epsilon})$ for some  $\epsilon > 0$ and
- the third case where $f \in \omega(n^{\log_b{a}})$ instead of $f \in \Omega(n^{\log_b{a}+\epsilon})$ for some $\epsilon > 0$

respectively.

Answer (score 2):

**No, that would be incorrect.**

Perhaps it is the condition $\varepsilon > 0$ which is the root of your confusion. It is supposed to mean that $\varepsilon$ is a real positive number and *constant* (with respect to $n$). If we allow $f \in \omega(n^{\log_b a})$, for instance, then for $a = b = 2$ we would have $f(n) = n \log n \in \Theta(n)$ as a consequence of the theorem, which is false.

---

On a side note, you write "$f$ must be asymptotically less than or equal to $n^{1.999\ldots}$". This *does* mean that $f$ must be bounded by $n^2$, though I believe not for the reasons you think it does. [Recall that $1.999\ldots = 2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...), so that statement is rather trivial...